# Calendar system booking error, PHP looping gone wrong

Tags: php, calendar

Currently I'm trying to make a booking system to look something like this(Easy done in HTML & a bit of PHP)

[image]

After applying the script and function, I get this:

[image]

Code:

```
function displayCalendar(){
    global $database;
    global $smarty;
    $sID = $_GET['serverid'];
    $database->query('SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE sID = :server');
    $database->bind(':server',$sID);
    $getServer = $database->fetchAll();
    $week = $_GET['week'];

    $times = array();
    for ($h = 6; $h < 18; $h++){
        for ($m = 0; $m < 60 ; $m += 60){
            $time = sprintf('%02d:%02d', $h, $m);
            $times["'$time'"] = "$time";
        }
    }

    $days = array(
        'Monday',
        'Tuesday',
        'Wednesday',
        'Thursday',
        'Friday',
        'Saturday',
        'Sunday',
    );

    echo '<tr>';
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 6; $i++) {
        echo '<th>'.$days[$i].'</th>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';

    foreach ($times as $time)
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        for($i = 0; $i <= 6; $i++) {
            foreach($getServer as $test => $row){
                if($row['time'] == $time && $row['day'] == $days[$i] && $row['week'] == $week)
                {
                    echo '<td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" aria-label="Left Align">'.$row['time'].'</button></td>';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" aria-label="Left Align"><a href="?page=booking&serverid='.$sID.'&week='.$week.'&day='.$days[$i].'&time='.$time.'">'.$time.'</a></button></td>';
                }
            }
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
```

Comment: you try using a different variable for the inner loop, lets say `$j`

Comment: as an advice, you should train yourself to separate code logic and presentation. first build your array to have a result structured, then juste display it in html.

Comment: Hi, the inner loop is not effected by the previous loop. 
Regarding for the advice, I do that. print_r(); but now the issue is for some reason when including a foreach loop from the database it does this.

Comment: That is more obvious with a correct code indenting.

Comment: Hehe, I don't really focus making my test codes looking fancy sadly.. But yes it was hard to see due of the indenting being poorly done, apologies. 

Still trying to figure this one out, has been wrecking m y head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a bit of changes to your code  but got it to work.

The key is the `hasData()` function which loops and if the data is found, it does a return which breaks the loop.

Your code continued the loop which echoed with each iteration.

```
function getData(){
    global $database;
    $sID = $_GET['serverid'];
    $database->query('SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE sID = :server');
    $database->bind(':server',$sID);
    $getServer = $database->fetchAll();

    return $getServer;
}


function hasData($getServer, $time, $day, $week, $sID){
    foreach($getServer as $row){
        if($row['time'] == $time && $row['day'] == $day && $row['week'] == $week)
        {
            return '<td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" aria-label="Left Align">'.$time.'</button></td>';
            break;
        }
    }
    return '<td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" aria-label="Left Align"><a href="?page=booking&serverid='.$sID.'&week='.$week.'&day='.$day.'&time='.$time.'">'.$time.'</a></button></td>';
}

function displayCalendar(){
    global $database, $smarty;
    $sID = $_GET['serverid'];
    $getServer = getData();

    $week = $_GET['week'];

    $times = array();
    for ($h = 6; $h < 18; $h++){
        for ($m = 0; $m < 60 ; $m += 60){
            $time = sprintf('%02d:%02d', $h, $m);
            $times["'$time'"] = "$time";
        }
    }

    $days = array(
        'Monday',
        'Tuesday',
        'Wednesday',
        'Thursday',
        'Friday',
        'Saturday',
        'Sunday',
    );

    echo '<tr>';
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 6; $i++) {
        echo '<th>'.$days[$i].'</th>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';

    foreach ($times as $time)
    {
        echo '<tr class="time">';
        for($i = 0; $i <= 6; $i++) {
            echo hasData($getServer, $time, $days[$i], $week, $sID);
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
```

Comment: A little more clean is required.

Comment: Works thaaaank uuuuuuuuu!